# Computing image integral

Tags: opencv

How do one find the mean, std dev, and gradient from image integral? Given an image such as follows:

[image: summed area table and normal table of numbers]

As shown in the figure above, to find the sum of the highlighted parts, `sum = C+A-B-D`.
So we have `sum = 22`.

How can I proceed next in order to find:

- Mean
- Std dev
- Gradient

Comment: I don't get your question at all. Can you improve it?

Comment: You want to find _mean_, _std dev_ and _gradient_ of some image part (ROI)?

Comment: I want to find the mean, std dev and gradient of all the image.

Comment: Well, surely you would be able to calculate the mean/std dev/gradient from an integral image, but it would be a lot easier in the original image.. 

The alogrithm mean/std dev/gradient for integral image is the same like for the original image.. you just need to "back calculate" each value (to get values from original image) -> there is really no reason to use the integral image for this.. just makes it harder and slower

If you want a "short form like sum=C+A-B-D" for dev/std dev/gardient ..., I don't think there is one.

Comment: At first, that's what I thought too @KoKuToru. But, I saw some say it is pretty fast by using integral. So, I might wanna try and see.

Comment: @MizukiKai OpenCV has `mean`, `meanStdDev` and `sobel`(or `laplacian`) functions. Why don't you use them??

Comment: I want to try using integral image to compute it. Well it's better to know all this stuff isn't it.

Comment: I don't think that it will improve speed for you, but anyway good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C+A-B-D` gives you the sum of the gray levels in the zone delimited by A,B,C,D, so, to get the mean you just need to dived it by the area of the zone:

```
mean = (C+A-B-D)/4
```

To get the dev, you must compute the sum of **square** area table (using `cv::integral` you can pass a additional parameters to get the sum of squares). Quoting [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation), the standard deviation is equal to the square root of (the average of the squares less the square of the average). So assuming A',B',C',D' the values in your **square** area table:

```
dev = sqrt((C'+A'-B'-D')/4 - (mean*mean))
```

So computing mean and dev using integral image is **very** fast using integral images, especially if you want to compute those quantities at random locations and on random size of image patches.

Concerning the gradient, it's more complex. Are you sure you do not want to use `sobel` operator?

Comment: You said computing mean and dev using integral image is fast especially at random location or size. Then do you mean it is slower to apply on the entire image? Is Sobel operator fast?

Comment: to compute the gradient, sobel is fast with a careful implementation (convolution in the frequency domain). If you have to get mean values at each pixel for a fixed-size neighnbourhood, using a boxFilter can be a good idea, maybe quicker but I'm not sure. it will be a matter of milliseconds in my opinion. But you dont get the dev in this way. Integral image is a good option when speed is required

Comment: @remi Are you sure the formula is right? for at least the mean value? isn't it (C+A-B-D)/4?

Answer (score 3):

If C+A-B-C is the sum of all gray levels in the zone, then the mean is not

```
mean = C+A-B-D/4
```

but

```
mean = C+A-B-D/K
```

where K is the number of graylevels in the zone.

Also,

```
dev = sqrt( C'+A'-B'-D'/4 - (mean*mean) )
```

is not the stdev, because

```
dev = sqrt( (1/N)*sum_N ( x_i - u )^2 )
```

the equation here is equivalent to

```
dev = sqrt( (1/N)*sum_N ( (x_i)^2 ) - u^2 )
```

those equations are not equivalent.

Comment: Actually, as I show in my answer, remi was on the right track to derive the standard deviation formula, he just stumbled on the averaging factor.

Answer (score 3):

What jmch didn't say is, if `sqrt( C'+A'-B'-D'/K - (mean*mean) )` is not how you compute the standard deviation from the integral image, then how you do it?

First, let me switch to [Python](http://python.org/) / [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) code, so we get a modicum of notation consistency and expressions are easier to check. Given a sample array X, say:

```
X = array([random() * 10.0 for i in range(0, 9)])
```

The [uncorrected sample standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Uncorrected_sample_standard_deviation) of `X` can be defined as:

```
std = (sum((X - mean(X)) ** 2) / len(X)) ** 0.5 # 1
```

Applying the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to `(X - mean(X)) ** 2` we get:

```
std = (sum(X ** 2 - X * 2 * mean(X) + mean(X) ** 2) / len(X)) ** 0.5 # 2
```

Given the [identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_%28mathematics%29#Identities) of the summation operation, we can make:

```
std = ((sum(X ** 2) - 2 * mean(X) * sum(X) + len(X) * mean(X) ** 2) / len(X)) ** 0.5 # 3
```

If we make `S = sum(X)`, `S2 = sum(X ** 2)`, `M = mean(X)` and `N = len(X)` we get:

```
std = ((S2 - 2 * M * S + N * M ** 2) / N) ** 0.5 # 4
```

Now for an image `I` and two integral images `P` and `P2` calculated from `I` (where `P2` is the integral image for squared pixel values), we know that, given the four edge coordinates `A = (i0, j0)`, `B = (i0, j1)`, `C = (i1, j0)` and `D = (i1, j1)`, the values of `S`, `S2`, `M` and `N` can be calculated for the range `I[A:D]` as:

```
S = P[A] + P[D] - P[B] - P[C]

S2 = P2[A] + P2[D] - P2[B] - P2[C]

N = (i1 - i0) * (j1 - j0)

M = S / N
```

Which can then be applied to equation (4) above yielding the standard deviation of the range `I[A:D]`.

**Edit:** It's not entirely necessary, but given that `M = S / N` we can apply the following substitutions and simplifications to equation (4):

```
std = ((S2 - 2 * M * S + N * M ** 2) / N) ** 0.5

std = ((S2 - 2 * (S / N) * S + N * (S / N) ** 2) / N) ** 0.5

std = ((S2 - 2 * ((S ** 2) / N) + (S ** 2 / N)) / N) ** 0.5

std = ((S2 - ((S ** 2) / N)) / N) ** 0.5

std = (S2 / N - (S / N) ** 2) ** 0.5 # 5
```

Which is quite close to the equation remi gave, actually.